# How to use click events in CKEditor..?

Tags: javascript, click, ckeditor

I am writing an small code to run on CKEditor document click event, but its not working. My code is,

```
var element = CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'Editor_TextArea' );
element.on( 'click', function( ev )
{
//mycode
   alert('ok');
  }
  );
```

Can anyone help me..

Comment: A little more information might help, is there an error? Are you doing this in a CKEditor plugin or outside the editor?

Comment: Thanks for ur rply.. I found the solution see my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That `CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'Editor_TextArea' );` is not giving any values for me..
So i used the below code and its works well.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['Editor_TextArea'].on('contentDom', function() {
    this.document.on('click', function(event){
         //your code
         alert('Click Event');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work `emailTemplateBody` is name of `textarea` field.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.emailTemplateBody

editor.on('contentDom', function () {

    var editable = editor.editable();

    editable.attachListener(editable, 'click', function () {
        console.log("click event");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
editor.editable().on('click', function (event) {
    //YOUR CODE GOES HERE 
});
```